Progressive matrix puzzle with circles and dots
This item was posted on reddit and there is not a clear explanation for the solution.
https://www.reddit.com/r/cognitiveTesting/comments/1dgkakw/answer_and_explanation_please/#lightbox


Welcome to PSE! We tend to avoid off-site resources, so would you be able to copy the full puzzle to this site, and leave the link as attribution to the original creator?

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!
